# php exec or pro_open C# exe OutOfMemoryException，CLI OK

Tags: c#, php, com, out-of-memory, exec

Environment:Win10 64bit, WAMP3.0.6 64bit(PHP v7.0.10,apache v2.4.23),ppt2png.exe(Written by C#,Call dcom PowerPoint Application)

1.php code :exec(ppt2png.exe,in ppt,out pngs).

```
<?php
//echo exec('whoami');
$cmd="D:\wamp64\www\convert\application\convert\util/../bin/ppt2png/ppt2img.exe D:\wamp64\www\convert\application\convert\util/../convert_tmp/ppt/ba228be6f2cfa6a6bc2a66878afacb662018-01-15-15-04-57-7206.pptx -t png -o D:\wamp64\www\convert\application\convert\util/../convert_tmp/png/ba228be6f2cfa6a6bc2a66878afacb662018-01-15-15-04-57-7206";
exec($cmd, $output, $status);
//var_dump($status);
var_dump($output);

// pro_open($cmd);

function pro_open($cmd)
{
    $cmdErrorTxt = "error-output.txt";
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
        1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
        2 => array("file", $cmdErrorTxt, "a"), 
    );

    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

    if (is_resource($process)) {

        fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        $return_value = proc_close($process);

        return $return_value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2.c# ppt2png.exe code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Usage: ppt2img <ppt|pptx> [options]
Option:
-t|--type <png|jpg>
-o|--output <dir>");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (args[i] == "--type" || args[i] == "-t")
                {
                    ++i;
                    imgType = args[i];
                }
                else if (args[i] == "--output" || args[i] == "-o")
                {
                    ++i;
                    outDir = args[i];
                }
                else if (inPpt.Length == 0)
                    inPpt = args[i];
                else
                    throw new Exception("Unknow option '" + args[i] + "'");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid args");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
            return;
        }

        outDir = Path.GetFullPath(outDir);
        inPpt = Path.GetFullPath(inPpt);
        baseName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inPpt);

        Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Powerpoint.Application");

        if (officeType == null)
        {
            // Powerpoint is not installed.   
            // Show message or alert that Powerpoint is not installed.
        }
        else
        {
            // Powerpoint is installed.    
            // Continue your work.
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(inPpt,
                                                                                                 MsoTriState.msoTrue /* ReadOnly=true */,
                                                                                                 MsoTriState.msoTrue /* Untitled=true */,
                                                                                                 MsoTriState.msoFalse /* WithWindow=false */);

        int count = presentation.Slides.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving slide {0} of {1}...", i + 1, count);
            string fmtI= i.ToString("000");
            String outName = String.Format(@"{0}\slide_{2}.{3}", outDir, baseName, fmtI, imgType);
            try
            {
                presentation.Slides[i + 1].Export(outName, imgType, width, height);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to export slide {0}", i + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                break;
            }
        }

        PowerPoint_App.Quit();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
```

This is correct when executed in cmd.

[executed in cmd alone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3PP.png)

[executed in cmd by php cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrX6g.png)

But wrong when executed by browser(when web server is Apache Or IIS) throwing OutOfMemoryException.

error-output.txt contains 'unhandled exception:  OutOfMemoryException.'.

C# log indicates that C# program stops at

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
```

But when web server is Nginx,there is no such exception,it works out.

Who can give me some tips? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a PHP problem. It's an issue with the ppt2png.exe program.   It's likely a PPT file that's too big or something but you should contact the original author of that program for support.

Comment: I am the original author of  ppt2png.exe, which is correct  when debugged and run alone,but with php exec + Apache  wrong,+ IIS wrong,+ Nginx right,Is this not odd？I have configured the dcom permisions and web server permisions。

Comment: OutOfMemoryException is thrown by .NET, not by PHP. I think the Symfony framework has a "OutOfMemoryException" but if you're not using Symfony, then it's coming from .NET. First, I would check the full task / process list (the one for ALL users) in case you have a leak in the VS debugger. Check the commit size of your processes and check disk space in case it's eating up virtual memory and -thinking- it's out of memory. Next, please post the EXACT error you're seeing in the browser. Finally, add file logging to ppt2png to record begin/end of your app to make sure it's running to completion.

Comment: Also, remove the php tag and add the c# tag instead to your question.

Comment: Bear in mind C#/.NET development is not always straightforward when it comes to memory management, particularly if you have unmanaged resources (e.g. bitmaps), so it might work when you run it under normal debugging circumstances and fail under other circumstances.

Comment: Oh, and people are probably downvoting your quesiton because of the lack of specifics (e.g. specific output, etc). For the record, I have NOT downvoted your quesiton - I'm trying to help you clean up the question and get a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but in case someone else has this issue - I had exactly the same issue with a C# program that used Interop to convert PPT slides to PNG on Windows Server 2008 R2. Called from command line worked perfectly, called from PHP via exec() gave Out of Memory error. Turned out I'd installed 64-bit Office 2016 but PHP was 32-bit. Reinstalling 32-bit Office solved the issue.  Maybe that helps someone.